# Where is the default behavior for object equality (`==`) defined?

Tags: python, python-internals, python-datamodel

According to the [`object.__eq__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__), the default (that is, in the `object` class) implementation for `==` is as follows:

```py
True if x is y else NotImplemented
```

Still following the [documentation for `NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented), I inferred that `NotImplemented` implies that the Python runtime will try the comparison the other way around. That is try `y.__eq__(x)` if `x.__eq__(y)` returns `NotImplemented` (in the case of the `==` operator).

Now, the following code prints `False` and `True` in python 3.9:

```py
class A:
   pass
print(A() == A())
print(bool(NotImplemented))
```

So my question is the following: where does the documentation mention the special behavior of `NotImplemented` in the context of `__eq__` ?

PS : I found an answer in [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/object.c#L686) but I guess that this must/should be somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation is misleading and there's actually an issue tracking it:https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83292

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134523/7517724 provides a link to the commit with GvRs explanation for the change, but that doesn't explain why it's not in the documentation.

Comment: I think it's interesting to note that `x = A()`, `y = A()`, `print(x==x)`, `print(x==y)` returns `True` and `False` respectively.

Comment: @BeRT2me That's because `x == x` compares them using identity first: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool

Comment: I thought this refers to the identity lookup in the memory register. But since A is not instantiated yet, it registers 2X inline?

Comment: @YaakovBressler They are both instantiated. I have no idea what you mean by "registers inline". In order for the objects in `A() == A()` to exist long enough to be compared, they have to be separate objects. The default logic will make them compare false, because they are not the same object.

Comment: @Craig as I have now put in my answer, it *is* in the documentation - just not *this part*.

Answer (score 6):

> According to the `object.__eq__()` documentation, the default (that is, in the object class) implementation for `==` is as follows

No; that is the default implementation **of `__eq__`**. `==`, being an operator, cannot be implemented in classes.

Python's implementation of operators is cooperative. There is hard-coded logic that uses the dunder methods to figure out what should happen, and possibly falls back on a default. This logic is outside of any class.

You can see another example with the built-in `len`: a class can return whatever it likes from its `__len__` method, and you can in principle call it directly and get a value of any type. However, this does not properly implement the protocol, and `len` will complain when it doesn't get a non-negative integer back. There is not any class which contains that type-checking and value-checking logic. It is external.

> Still following the documentation for `NotImplemented`, I inferred that `NotImplemented` implies that the Python runtime will try the comparison the other way around. That is try `y.__eq__(x)` if `x.__eq__(y)` returns `NotImplemented` (in the case of the `==` operator).

`NotImplemented` is **just an object**. It is not syntax. It does not have any special behavior, and in Python, simply returning a value does not trigger special behavior besides that the value is returned.

The external code for binary operators will try to look for the matching `__op__`, and try to look for the matching `__rop__` if `__op__` didn't work. At this point, `NotImplemented` is not an acceptable answer (it is a sentinel that exists specifically for this purpose, because `None` **is** an acceptable answer). **In general**, if the answer so far is still `NotImplemented`, then the external code will `raise NotImplementedError`.

**As a special case**, objects that don't provide their own comparison (i.e., the default from `object` is used for `__eq__` or `__ne__`) will compare as "not equal" unless they are identical. The [C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/object.c#L686) repeats the identity check (in case a class *explicitly* defines `__eq__` or `__ne__` to `return NotImplemented` directly, I guess). This is because it is considered sensible to give this result, and obnoxious to make `==` fail all the time when there is a sensible default.

However, the two objects are still not *orderable* without explicit logic, since there isn't a reasonable default. (You could compare the pointer values, but they're arbitrary and don't have anything to do with the Python logic that got you to that point; so ordering things that way isn't realistically useful for writing Python code.) So, for example, `x < y` will raise a `TypeError` if the comparison logic isn't provided. (It does this *even if* `x is y`; you could reasonably say that `<=` and `>=` should be true in this case, and `<` and `>` should be false, but it makes things too complicated and is not very useful.)

> [Observation: `print(bool(NotImplemented))` prints `True`]

Well, yes; `NotImplemented` is an object, so it's truthy by default; and it doesn't represent a numeric value, and isn't a container, so there's no reason for it to be falsy.

However, that also doesn't tell us anything useful. We don't care about the truthiness of `NotImplemented` here, and it isn't used that way in the Python implementation. It is **just** a sentinel value.

> where does the documentation mention the special behavior of NotImplemented in the context of `__eq__` ?

Nowhere, because it *isn't a behavior of `NotImplemented`*, as explained above.

Okay, but that leaves underlying question: where does the documentation explain what the `==` operator does by default?

Answer: because we are talking about an operator, and not about a method, it's not in the section about dunder methods. It's in section 6, which talks about expressions. Specifically, [6.10.1. Value comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons):

> The default behavior for equality comparison (`==` and `!=`) is based on the identity of the objects. Hence, equality comparison of instances with the same identity results in equality, and equality comparison of instances with different identities results in inequality. A motivation for this default behavior is the desire that all objects should be reflexive (i.e. `x is y` implies `x == y`).

Comment: The last part is where I looked as well and it didn't quite fully convince me, the "equality comparison of instances with different identities results in inequality" could just mean that `!=` results in `True`. But I guess you're right, it's supposed to also mean that `==` results in `False`.

Comment: `(x == y) == not (x != y)` is a separate invariant, listed later in the section: "Inverse comparison should result in the boolean negation. In other words, the following expressions should have the same result:".

Comment: That's under *"User-defined classes that customize their comparison behavior should"*, though, so it's talking about what *our* classes *should* do at the `__eq__` level. Not about what Python does do at the `==` level.

Comment: I guess, but I feel like we're getting into serious nitpicking now.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I still believe that the documentation could be way more clear. We can read "`x==y calls x.__eq__(y)`" and "By default, object implements `__eq__()` by using is, returning `NotImplemented` in the case of a false comparison: `True if x is y else NotImplemented`."  in the data model section of the documentation. Reading this, and not knowing that section 6 speaks also about `==`, I was lost.

Comment: There are many places where the documentation could be more clear. The dev team has recently been turning more attention to that sort of thing, which is part of the same effort as 3.10's improved error messages.