# Please explain about comparing objects in Python

Tags: python, compare

```py
#python strange compare
import pickle
import os.path
class Example:
    def __init__(self, test01, test02, test03):
        self.test01 = test01
        self.test02 = test02
        self.test03 = test03

Data01 = []
for x in range(0, 3):
    Temp1 = Example("t1","t2","t3")
    Temp1.test01 = "aa"+str(x)
    Temp1.test02 = "bb"+str(x)
    Temp1.test03 = "cc"+str(x)
    Data01.append(Temp1)
    del Temp1

MyEx1 = Data01
MyEx2 = Data01[1:]

Data02 = []
for x in range(0, 3):
    Temp1 = Example("t1","t2","t3")
    Temp1.test01 = "aa"+str(x)
    Temp1.test02 = "bb"+str(x)
    Temp1.test03 = "cc"+str(x)
    Data02.append(Temp1)
    del Temp1
print("Example1")
print(MyEx1[1] == MyEx2[0]) #this is fine
print("Example2 - WHAT")
print(MyEx1[0] == Data02[0])
print("1", MyEx1[0].test01, " 2 ", Data02[0].test01)
print(MyEx1[0].test01 == Data02[0].test01)

with open("exa_file01.exm", 'wb') as tmp:  #write to a file
    pickle.dump(MyEx2 , tmp)
    tmp.close

tmp3 = open("exa_file01.exm", "rb")
MyEx3 = pickle.load(tmp3)
print("Example3")
print(MyEx1[1] == MyEx3[0])
print(MyEx1[1].test01 == MyEx3[0].test01)
print(MyEx1[1].test02 == MyEx3[0].test02)
print(MyEx1[1].test03 == MyEx3[0].test03)

print("Example4")
print(MyEx2[0] == MyEx3[0])
print(MyEx2[0].test01 == MyEx3[0].test01)
print(MyEx2[0].test02 == MyEx3[0].test02)
print(MyEx2[0].test03 == MyEx3[0].test03)
```

Results

```
Example1
True
Example2 - WHAT
False
1 aa0  2  aa0
True
Example3
False
True
True
True
```

Python 3.7 - Windows

Clarify Python behavior in object comparison

**
that is, Python cannot compare objects if they are slightly more complex than a string or numbers

that is, for complex arrays of objects “a in array b” does not work, set does not work. Clearly understood.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72440058/where-is-the-default-behavior-for-object-equality-defined

Comment: Your expression: `MyEx1[1] == MyEx2[0]` is `True` because they are the same object. Your expression `MyEx1[1] == MyEx3[0]` is `False` because they are different objects (even though they have the same values of attributes).

Comment: >> Your expression MyEx1[1] == MyEx3[0] is False because they are different objects (even though they have the same values of attributes).  >> Well, I can to do different obj like M1 = 1 ; M2 = 1 , it's different

Comment: got it. Data02 = []
for x in range(0, 3):
    Temp1 = Example("t1","t2","t3")
    Temp1.test01 = "aa"+str(x)
    Temp1.test02 = "bb"+str(x)
    Temp1.test03 = "cc"+str(x)
    Data02.append(Temp1)
    del Temp1
print("Example1")
print(MyEx1[1] == MyEx2[0]) #this is fine
print("Example2 - WHAT")
print(MyEx1[0] == Data02[0])
print("1", MyEx1[0].test01, " 2 ", Data02[0].test01)
print(MyEx1[0].test01 == Data02[0].test01)

Comment: I added an example in the code to make it clearer.

Comment: `"Python cannot compare objects ..."`. Of course it can. What python does for its own types, you can do for yours. You can override `__eq__()` for your own classes. (Also note that `dataclass` *can* do it for you).

Comment: ''' You can override __eq__() for your own classes. ''' - It hasn’t become any easier at all, and besides, I don’t understand how “if x is in y” will work in this case.