# Why doesn't comparing an int to a str raise a TypeError?

Tags: python

Why does this code print "not equals" instead of throwing a TypeError?

```
int_num = 1
str_num = "2"

if str_num == int_num:
    print("equal")
else:
    print("not equal")
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to throw a TypeError?

Comment: You can compare ints with strings they just don't compare equally.

Comment: Because it's not a type error to compare objects of two different types for equality.  (You will get a TypeError if you do an inequality comparison, like `int_num < str_num`, because there isn't any defined behavior for deciding whether a string is greater or lesser than a number.)

Comment: Please provide a reference to docs that made you believe that `TypeEroor` was to be triggered.

Comment: @Wondercricket Because it’s a very controversial, and arguably incorrect, API design. There are reasons why Python does it like this but it’s far from the only conceivable implementation, and it’s almost certainly not the best.

Comment: It's pretty unambiguous that `1` is not the same as `"2"`, so returning `False` seems unambiguously correct to me...

Comment: Because Guido, and the rest of the Python crowd, decided many years ago that comparing objects of different types should not be an error. This may or may not have been wise, but that's the way it is. (Now do JavaScript.)

Comment: @Wondercricket It's a reasonable expectation. Plenty of languages will throw type errors either at compile-time or run-time. It just so happens Python isn't one of them. I mean the language does has a `TypeError` exception which indicates it does do type checks in some capacity. I'm not surprised the OP is surprised.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's the better or worse choice, this feels like a "why was this language design choice made" question which are typically discouraged due to their subjective nature.

Comment: Apart from being opinion based and not a very useful question (the obvious answer is *this is how the language was designed*), this is just a duplicate... Does this answer your question? [Python: Why does equality comparing an int with a string not throw an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10617737/6045800)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Duplicate, for sure. “Not very useful”, I find debatable: it’s a surprising behaviour to some, and it trips plenty of people up, despite being documented as such.

Comment: Did not expected the question to be controversial. Coming from a Java background it was surprising and odd but 'it is what it is'.  Next time I'll know to check before scratching my head for hours :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the current Python documentation for [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> **Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never compare equal.** The `==` operator is always defined...

(Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 3):

How [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) are defined for standard types:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never compare equal. The `==` operator is always defined but for some object types (for example, class objects) is equivalent to `is`. The `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` operators are only defined where they make sense; for example, they raise a `TypeError` exception when one of the arguments is a complex number.
>
> Non-identical instances of a class normally compare as non-equal unless the class defines the `__eq__()` method.

[Equality](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) would work on any objects though:

> By default, object implements `__eq__()` by using `is`, returning `NotImplemented` in the case of a false comparison: `True if x is y else NotImplemented`.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question. It's comparing an `int` and a `str` and asking why there is no type error

Comment: It is the only possible objective answer besides digging threads from 20 years ago regarding Python's design.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy You are right, added a part on standard types and kept the part on general objects... Will improve it more.